If i write the BL partition in Odin, will i still be able to boot in Download mode?
I'm doing a risky thing to my old open-sourced Galaxy phone, and if i didn't know about this, my phone would then be able to be a brick for my house. If anyone knows this, please contact me!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I mean i'm trying to embed some code into the bootloader (BL partition) in odin, but if there is the case where the phone does not work with my code, can i reboot to Download mode and revert anything to the default?
